# Requests ChunkedEncodingError

Tags: python

Error message: requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(9955 bytes read, 285 more expected)', IncompleteRead(9955 bytes read, 285 more expected))

The error occurs infrequently and seemingly randomly. The function below is run every minute as I am trying to get text from a website using Beautiful Soup. Is this a problem with my code or the website? And is there a way to ignore this error and simply return "0" so that the loop can continue? Thanks.

```
def getInfo():
    url = websiteURL
    session = requests.Session()
    adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=10)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    r = session.get(url)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
        if (len(soup.find_all('div', class_ = className)[0]) >0):
            values.append(soup.find_all('div', class_ = className)[0].find('span').text)
```

Comment: Wrap the code in a `try: ... except ChunkedEncodingError as e: ...` block, and in the `except` return the value "0"

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it